# Склонение топонимов, оканчивающихся на букву "о"

Tags: топонимика

Какие падежные окончания слов *Колпино, Пушкино, Лемболово*?

Comment: См также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/%d0%92-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439628/%d0%92-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/8655#8655

Answer (score 3):

По правилам такие названия склоняются как существительные среднего рода. В творительном падеже - Колпином, Пушкином, Лембловом. Остальные падежи сомнений не вызывают.

Подробно см. здесь: http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90

А, вот ещё. В принципе у географических названий может быть множественное число: *"Под Питером - Пушкино, под Москвой - Пушкино, запутался я с этими Пушкин**ами**".* Хотя в рельной речи такое, конечно, вряд ли встретится.

Comment: Под Питером - Пушкин

Comment: Считайте, что говорящий этого не знал. Я же вам не по географии отвечаю. Хотя в принципе можно и "Пушкин" поставить.

Answer (score 0):

"Приехал из Колпина"-разве ухо не режет?

Comment: Мне режет, когда не склоняют.  
А вам Михаил Юрьевич ответил:  
Недаром помнит вся Россия  
Про день Бородин**а**.

Answer (score 0):

Мне тоже не режет из Колпина, из Сормова, из Канавина. Режет "в центре Сормово". Но вот что интересно. Не хотят склонять свои топонимы, оканчивающиеся на -о, местные жители. Гости делают это легко и правильно.