# В Болдине или в Болдино?

Tags: грамотная-речь, ономастика, топонимика

Не могу понять, склоняются или нет русские топонимы, оканчивающиеся на о? 
*Скажу тебе (за тайну) что я в Болдине писал...* (из письма Пушкина Плетнёву) - склоняется.
*В первых числах октября Пушкин попытался уехать из Болдино* (из Википедии) - не склоняется.
Дачи писателей в Переделкине, но самолёт приземлился в Домодедово...

Comment: Также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%be/37668#37668

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439628/%d0%92-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5

Comment: И еще:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/8655#8655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не склоняются топонимы на -ово, -ёво, -ино, -ыно, если 1) они выступают в качестве приложения при словах *город, станция, село, поселок*, реже - *город*: *в селе Захарково, к деревне Белкино, до поселка Пушкино*; 2) если населенный пункт назван по фамилии известного лица: *близ Репино* (название поселка), *командировка в Кирово*.   Если же топоним используется без существительного, обозначающего родовое понятие, то он склоняется: *усадьба в Абрамцеве, гостить в Болдине, письмо из Одинцова, битва под Бородином*. 
Но в последнее время наметилась тенденция к несклоняемости: *вышли из поезда в Одинцово, отдыхать в Абрамцево, в небе над Тушино*. Первоначально несклоняемые формы употреблялись только в профессиональной речи географов и военных, чтобы избежать смешения их с одноименными называниями без окончания -о: *Киров* и *Кирово*, *Пушкин* и *Пушкино*.