# Склонение названий населённых пунктов

Tags: грамотная-речь, топонимика

Раньше, я помню, не принято было склонять названия населенных пунктов, например: *"Сегодня погода в ОдинцовО 15 С"*, сейчас почему то пошла мода на склонение. В частности, она насаждается нашим доблестным ТВ, например, говорят: *"Сегодня погода в ОдинцовЕ 15 С"*

Какая все таки версия более правильна?

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%be/37668#37668

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/%d0%92-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439628/%d0%92-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§ 1220. Географические названия на -ово, -ево и -ино, -ыно: Иваново, Бирюлево, Кунцево, Сараево, Болдино, Бородино, Голицыно и под. в современной разговорной, профессиональной, газетной речи обнаруживают тенденцию к неизменяемости. Несмотря на это в письменной речи, в соответствии с действующими грамматическими правилами, географические названия на -ов(о), -ёв(о), -ев(о), -ин(о), -ын(о) склоняются: В небе над Тушином (газ.); Речь идет об аэропорте в Шереметьеве (газ.). Несклоняемость географических наименований нормальна в следующих случаях.

1) Если такое наименование является приложением к одному из следующих обобщающих слов: село, деревня, поселок, станция, становище, реже – город: в селе Васильково, в поселке Пушкино, в деревне Белкино, на станции Гоголева.

2) Если населенный пункт назван собственным именем известного лица: около Репино (назв. поселка под Ленинградом), недалеко от Лермонтово (назв. небольшого города около Пензы).*(http://rusgram.narod.ru/1216-1231.html#1220)*

Answer (score 2):

Если бы город назывался Одинцов, то *"погода в Одинцове"* было бы вполне грамотно, но я думаю, что, заканчиваясь на "о", это слово сразу становится не склоняемым. Такая же ситуация, например, с фамилиями западно-славянского  происхождения (Украина, Беларусь), которые заканчиваются на "о": Кличко, Тимошенко, Лукашенко и т.п.

Comment: Этот вопрос уже необнократно обсуждался на нашем форуме. Например [здесь](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/2640/топонимика-склонение-топонимов-на-о), [здесь](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/4488/орфография-склонение-названия-города) и [здесь](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/5245/грамотная-речь-в-болдине-или-в-болдино).