# В Кемерово или в Кемерове?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, ономастика, названия, топонимика

На "России 24" в связи с трагедией непрерывно идут новости из г. Кемерово.

Как на экране, так и вслух - говорят/пишут "в Кемерове"

Это ведь неправильно?

Comment: Повтор вопроса о топонимах на О: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/%D0%92-%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В Болдине или в Болдино?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/%d0%92-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%be/37668#37668

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/8655#8655

Comment: Спасибо Вам за внимание к моему вопросу.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ галочкой, если он оказался полезным.

Answer (score 3):

**Ке́мерово** — город в России, административный центр Кемеровской области, то есть **хорошо известный топоним**, который по общим правилам **должен склоняться.**

Обычно не склоняются малоизвестные населенные пункты для сохранения точности их названий.

**Особое место занимают топонимы на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно,** так как при склонении  могут не различаться формы м.р и ср.р: в Пушкино или в Пушкине. Для них действуют особые правила.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters?id=73

В Переделкино или в Переделкине?

Топонимы славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно, **не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом**: из района Люблино, **Если же родового слова нет, то возможны оба варианта, склоняемый и несклоняемый:** в Люблине и в Люблино,

При этом **склоняемый вариант соответствует строгой литературной норме**. Словарь Л. К. Граудиной, В. А. Ицковича, Л. П. Катлинской «Грамматическая правильность русской речи» указывает: «В образцовом литературном стиле (со сцены, с телеэкрана, в радиоречи) эти формы следует склонять».

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: в Кемерове. Это соответствует строгой литературной норме

> Если родового слова нет, то возможны оба варианта, склоняемый и несклоняемый: в Люблине и в Люблино, в сторону Строгина и в сторону Строгино, в Иванове и в Иваново, из Простоквашина и из Простоквашино, до Косова и до Косово, к Митину и к Митино, 8-й микрорайон Митина и 8-й микрорайон Митино. При этом **склоняемый вариант соответствует строгой литературной норме**. Словарь Л. К. Граудиной, В. А. Ицковича, Л. П. Катлинской «Грамматическая правильность русской речи» указывает: «**В образцовом литературном стиле (со сцены, с телеэкрана, в радиоречи) эти формы следует склонять**».
>   [(В Переделкино или в Переделкине?)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

См. как склоняется Кемерово в [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE).