# В городе Кемерове

Tags: топонимика, приложение

Я уверен, что этот вопрос обсуждался здесь неоднократно, но всё же мне интересна несколько иная его сторона.

Я окончил школу в этом году. Учился именно в этом городе. В средних классах нам неоднократно говорили о том, что название нашего города склоняется, то есть следует говорить, что мы живём в Кемерове. При этом, если перед словом "Кемерово" стоит слово "город", склонять его не нужно, то есть следует говорить, что мы живём в городе Кемерово. Общаясь с представителями более старших поколений, я понял, что в их школах это правило им доносили иначе: следует говорить, что мы живём в городе Кемерово, подразумевая несклоняемость слова. Последнее время в официальных документах я всё чаще замечаю, что подобные предложения оформляются именно так, как я написал в заголовке, так же по аналогии с другими городами, за исключением действительно несклоняемых названий населённых пунктов (Хельсинки) и названий, содержащих множественное число (Большие Коты). Вопрос в следующем: действительно ли изменялась тенденция к склонению населённых пунктов или люди, являющиеся носителями языка иного образца, так сказать, "невнимательно слушали в школах"? Если да, есть ли документы, в которых можно это проследить, или это произошло само собой? И как всё-таки выглядит правило для современного языка?

Comment: Конечно же, вопрос на сайте обсуждался. Вот здесь: **В Кемерово или в Кемерове?** https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439628/%d0%92-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5

Answer (score 2):

> При этом, если перед словом "Кемерово" стоит слово "город", склонять
>   его не нужно, то есть следует говорить, что мы живём в городе
>   Кемерово. Общаясь с представителями более старших поколений, я понял,
>   что в их школах это правило им доносили иначе: следует говорить, что
>   мы живём в городе Кемерово, подразумевая несклоняемость слова.

Я не совсем понимаю, в чем разница. Хотя и то и другое не совсем верно. 
Топонимы при родовом слове город обычно склоняются, за исключением славянских топонимов на -ово, -ево, -ино. Кемерово в этот список вроде бы попадает. Но даже с такими названиями использование слова "город" нецелесообразно. Правда, в отношении последнего есть оговорки, но с ними еще надо разбираться.

Вот что пишет "Грамота"

...

> Топонимы славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на -ово, -ево,
>   -ино, -ыно, не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом: из района Люблино, в сторону района Строгино, к району Митино, в городе Иваново,
>   из деревни Простоквашино, до края Косово.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90

Но при этом

> В «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К. Чельцовой
>   указано, что «сокращение г. (город), как и полное слово, рекомендуется
>   употреблять ограниченно, главным образом перед названиями городов,
>   образованными от фамилий (г. Киров)».

Там же.

То есть вариант "в городе Кемерово" нормативен в части несклонения и сомнителен стилистически.

Кстати говоря, причина этой оговорки для рассматриваемых топонимов сама по себе не совсем понятна. В старой норме её не было (можно вспомнить хотя бы "Историю села Горюхина").

Answer (score 1):

"Мы живём в городе Кемерово" - точно не ошибка. Современные официальные правила требуют, однако, чтобы при опускании видового наименования ("городе, селе") подобные названия склонялись - так говорят в Москве (где и утверждаются правила) "со времён Бородина". В Петербурге (и окружающей области) так не говорят и не пишут в газетах (там принято "вблизи Колпино", "рядом с Комарово" и т. д.). В этом смысле вам предлагают компромисс между (по-видимому) традиционным для ваших мест употреблением таких названий и принятием противоречащих ему правил. Отказ от склонения характерен (независимо от общих правил) для военной практики, где это позволяет восстановить неискажённое название из косвенного падежа (напр. не спутать Комарово и Комаров, Пушкино и Пушкин).

Answer (score 1):

Билет до Кемерово/Кемерова, города Кемерово.

> Географические названия славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на **-ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно,** не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом: из района Люблино, в сторону района Строгино, к району Митино, в городе Иваново, из деревни Простоквашино, до края Косово. Если же родового слова нет, то возможны **оба варианта**, склоняемый (старый) и несклоняемый (новый): в Люблине и в Люблино, в сторону Строгина и в сторону Строгино, в Иванове и в Иваново, из Простоквашина и из Простоквашино, до Косова и до Косово, к Митину и к Митино, 8-й микрорайон Митина и 8-й микрорайон Митино. При этом склоняемый вариант соответствует строгой литературной норме. 
>   Словарь Л. К. Граудиной, В. А. Ицковича, Л. П. Катлинской «Грамматическая правильность русской речи» указывает: «В образцовом литературном стиле (со сцены, с телеэкрана, в радиоречи) эти формы следует склонять».

История вопроса подробно рассматривается здесь

http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy